# JavaFX8 and FXML different user directories?

Tags: java, javafx-8, fxml, filestructure

I'm developing a JavaFX application with FXML and Java files. Therefore I have this filestructure:
Project/src/com.company.application.project (here are the java, fxml and css files)
Project/img (here are the images which should be loaded by fxml or java)

To access an image out of a FXML I have to declare the path like this:

```
<Image url="@../../../../../../img/Remove.png" />
```

And in Java I declare it like that:

```
Image img = new Image(new FileInputStream("img/Remove.png"));
```

So my question is, why are the paths different? I would like to declare paths in FXML like in Java with "img/Remove.png" without the ugly dots. How can I make this? I don't want to create folders on different locations...

Regards

Comment: If you place your FXML and PNG files in the same folder then you can call the image like this: <Image url="@Remove.png" />

Comment: That's the point. I want to locate images in a different folder named "img" in the project folder. My question is, how is it possible to declare paths in FXML like in Java only with "img/image.png"?

Comment: According to http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html it seems that this is the only way to specify the location. See section Location Resolution.